# VS Code Python debugging prompts a path error, though running any program works fine

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I don't have any problems running any python program, but if I try to debug it, message prompts "The python path in your debug configuration is invalid" and nothing happens.

[message prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVQXs.png) <--

For some people with similar problem adding "python.pythonPath" to launch.json helped, but it doesn't work in my case. The path in launch.json is correct, as it's the same path used in settings.json for Python extention.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

It turns out that PyCharm messed something up.

I deleted all the paths in PATH, that were refering to PyCharm, and now it's all ok for some reason.